# RDF - Distributing rdf:type to all items in the list

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs, turtle-rdf

Consider the following RDF:

```
semapi:BaseClass     a rdfs:Class; 
                     rdfs:subClassOf rdfs:Class .

semapi:hasChainTo a rdf:Property; 
                   rdfs:domain semapi:BaseClass;
                   rdfs:range  semapi:BaseClass .                   

semapi:DerivedClass  a rdfs:Class; rdfs:subClassOf semapi:BaseClass .                  

instances:Instance1 a semapi:DerivedClass;
                    semapi:hasChainTo (
                        [
                            a semapi:DerivedClass;
                                    semapi:hasChainTo (
                                           [C1]
                                           [C2]
                                    )
                            ]
                     )
```

If `semapi:hasChainTo rdfs:range semapi:BaseClass` then it implies *the list* is `rdf:type semapi:BaseClass`.

What I really mean to say is each *item* in the list is `rdf:type` (ei. `[C1] rdf:type semapi:BaseClass`, `[C2] rdf:type semapi:BaseClass`, ...)

How can I do this? Do I need Owl (preferably not)?

Comment: I'm glad to see this posted as a question, but can you clarify what you mean by "If semapi:hasChainTo rdfs:range semapi:BaseClass then it implies ([C1][C2]) rdf:type semapi:BaseClass."?  I don't really follow.  You want to get from `x hasChainTo (A B C)` to `x a A`, `x a B`, `x a C`, right?

Comment: You mention that you don't want to use OWL (which I presume means you don't want to use an OWL reasoner).  From [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069961/protege-4-saving-rdf-reformats-nested-blank-nodes), it sounds like you are planning on using an RDFS reasoner. What might be an option for this problem probably depends on what kind of reasoners you can use.  Allegro RDFS++, which you mentioned in the other question, has a Prolog interface, so that could help.  You can also do this using SPARQL.  Except for the RDF lists, OWL property chains could also help.

Comment: Sorry I rewrote the OP a little to be more clear, it's the same example you gave in the other answer where I want to say each item in the list is some type NOT the list itself is that type. I already have `[ a semapi:DerivedClass; ]` type declaration in each item, however you pointed out that by `semapi:BaseClass rdfs:range semapi:BaseClass` I'm saying that the list itself is type `semapi:BaseClass`. Is `rdfs:range` the right predicate? Can I say "rdfs:range  List<semapi:BaseClass>"? (pseudo code)

Comment: Actually, what's the purpose of the list?  You can write `x a C1, C2, C3, C4.` in Turtle/N3, after all.  Is there something in particular that makes the list necessary.  In RDFS you could says that `sem:hasClass rdfs:subPropertyOf rdF:type`, and then write `x sem:hasClass C1, C2, C3, C4.` and an RDFS reasoner would take care of the rest.  Why do you want the list in the first place?

Comment: I'm basically modeling a natural language autocomplete that lets the user build out a sentance (or command) "step-wise". This means that the preservation of context many levels deep is critical because the "next" autocomplete options are not just based on the last but also on last -1, last -2, last -3, ...  So `a hasChain b` cannot be generalized to be always true if it only exists at a certain level in the hierarchy. Such a chain may only exist at that level of the hierarchy and no where else. That's why I'm using lists and blank nodes. Does that make any sense? I can try to clarify further.

Comment: I'm not sure I followed all of that, but the specifics don't really matter, I guess (I mean, they do, but not in terms of making a property distribute over a list).  I just wanted to make sure that it wasn't purely a syntactic issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on how you want to do this, you have a few options.  I think you're trying to stick to non-OWL reasoning, so we'll make sure to include such a solution, but I do want to touch on an OWL solution too, since for some similar situations, it works very well.

### Using OWL and a custom ObjectList

If you *do* have the option of using an OWL reasoner, then this is a nice case in which you can create your own list vocabulary and use some property chains.  The idea is that you introduce a class `List` with an individual `nil`, and properties `first` and `rest`.  You're really just copying the vocabulary  in your own namespace.  Then lets say you define two properties

- `likes`: relates an individual X to another individual Y; "X likes Y".
- `likesList`: relates an individual X to a List (not an RDF list, though) of individuals that X likes.

Then you can introduce two property chain axioms

- `likesList subPropertyChain likesList o rest`: if X likesList (_ ...), then X likesList (...).

This way, from `X likes (A B C)` we get `X likes (A B C)`, `X likes (B C)`, `X likes (C)`, and `X likes nil`.

- `likes subPropertyChain likesList o first`: if X likesList (A ...), then X likes A.

Then, from all those inferred statements above, we get `X likes A`, `X likes B`, and `X likes C`.

In Turtle, this looks like:

```
@prefix :        <http://www.example.org/distributing#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

<http://www.example.org/distributing>
      a       owl:Ontology .

:List
      a       owl:Class .

:nil  a       :List , owl:NamedIndividual .

:first
      a       owl:ObjectProperty .

:rest
      a       owl:ObjectProperty .

:likes
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      owl:propertyChainAxiom
              (:likesList :first) .

[]    a       owl:Axiom ;
      rdfs:comment "If X likesList (A ...), then X likes A." ;
      owl:annotatedProperty
              owl:propertyChainAxiom ;
      owl:annotatedSource :likes ;
      owl:annotatedTarget (:likesList :first) .

:likesList
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:comment "Relates an individual I1 to a ObjectList of individuals that I1 likes." ;
      owl:propertyChainAxiom
              (:likesList :rest) .

[]    a       owl:Axiom ;
      rdfs:comment "If X likesList (A B C), then since (B C) is the rest of (A B C), X likesList (B C), too." ;
      owl:annotatedProperty
              owl:propertyChainAxiom ;
      owl:annotatedSource :likesList ;
      owl:annotatedTarget (:likesList :rest) .
```

This gets a bit inconvenient if you have to write the RDF manually, since you have to do

```
X :likesList [ :first A ;
               :rest [ :first B ;
                       :rest [ :first C ;
                               :rest nil ] ] ] .
```

and can't use the nice `(...)` syntax that Turtle includes.  This also really doesn't help for the case that you've got, since OWL classes aren't individuals, so they can't be the object of object properties, and `rdf:type` isn't an object property.  I just wanted to include this because it's a nice way for an object property to distribute over a (non-RDF) list of individuals, and because the approach makes the following solutions clearer.

### Using SPARQL queries

Given data like:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:X :pList (:A :B :C :D) .
```

A SPARQL query like

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

construct { 
  ?x :p ?y 
} 
where { 
  ?x :pList/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?y
}
```

produces

```
@prefix :        <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

:X    :p            :A ;
      :p            :C ;
      :p            :B ;
      :p            :D .
```

In imitation of the the OWL based approach above, I used two properties `pList` and `p`, but they could be the same, in which case `p` would be "distributed" over the list.

With a datastore somewhere, you should be able to do a SPARQL update using `insert/where`:

```
prefix : <http://example.org/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

insert { 
  ?x :p ?y 
} 
where { 
  ?x :pList/rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?y
}
```

to add the data to the store.

### Using a Prolog like syntax

If you want to actually get this reasoning to be performed with a reasoner, you'll be in the domain of reasoner specific stuff.  However, lots of reasoners support a Prolog-like query language, and you can write these rules there, too.  I don't know AllegoGraph's RDFS++ syntax, but the general structure would include some definitions like:

```
?x p ?y :- ?x pList ?list, ?list rdf:first ?y

?x pList ?l :- ?x pList ?list, ?list rdf:rest ?l
```

Comment: Can I set a bounty for you to complete this answer with the non-Owl solution? I'd really like to maintain my original syntax (using nested RDF lists).

Comment: @parliament I'd be happy to update the answer, regardless of bounty (but if you award it anyway, I'll still say "thank you" :)), but can you clarify exactly what you mean?  The SPARQL solution didn't make any use of OWL, so it's a "non-Owl solution", isn't it?  To adapt that part of the solution, all you need to do is replace `:pList` with `semapi:hasChainTo` and `:p` by `rdf:type`, unless I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Joshua thanks. I didn't realize you meant the SPARQL as the "non-Owl" solution . I didn't consider is as such since I'd have to use SPARQL to query regardless and already have working queries written for the RDF in the OP. I thought what you meant by a "non-Owl" solution is an RDF/RDFS only solution that would allow me to continue using turtle lists syntax (since you mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18085739/1267778) that " Protégé is discarding a bunch of information that isn't meaningful to it as the RDF serialization of an OWL ontology").

Comment: I'm looking for a non-owl solution so that Protege would accept the RDF lists as valid RDF not "RDF serialization of OWL".

Comment: @parliament I'm sorry, I'm still not quite clear what you mean;  does the SPARQL solution (with appropriate changes made) work or not?  It's pure RDF, and doesn't use any OWL.  Protégé 4.x is an OWL-based tool and doesn't support plain RDFS ontologies.  If you want RDFS support, you'll need to use Protégé 3.x. What languages the various versions of Protégé support is orthogonal to whether a given solution uses OWL or not.